# The status of an OpenMP (C) idle thread

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

How is an idle thread of a team recognised in an OpenMP (C) code running on Linux? 
I want to measure the idle-time of the threads working as a team. Is it possible? Is there any field to show the status of a thread?

Comment: Just get the (still) free Oracle Solaris Studio (despite its name, it also has Linux version). It includes the Thread Analyzer instrument, which is able to gather thread utilisation information and to present it in a nice GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the `Status` field in `/proc/self/task/$tid/status` where `tid` is your task id (unique to each thread) acquired by `gettid()` syscall

It is also the third field in `/proc/self/task/$tid/stat`

`/proc/self/task/$tid/stat` will also contain `utime` and `stime` fields for each task so you can get their "active time". Check http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc to see which fields those are.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to correspond the omp_get_thread_num() to the gettid() result?

Comment: I am afraid not. `omp_get_thread_num()` is process-specific and normally counts from 0. While `gettid()` is a kernel `pid_t`. It is in essence the same as a process id PID, just more specific and indeed the TID of the main task/thread within a process is identical with the process PID. You will need to call `gettid()` from each thread to determine their ids or enumerate the directory `/proc/self/task`.